# Illustrator: complex artwork takes too long to redraw

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, workflow

I have eliminated thousands of points on a map exported to Illustrator. The redraw time is still 10-15 seconds after each click, even in Outline mode. The file size is not that large. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Can't help without seeing the file or the outlines. It might still be a complex vector, or have raster images linked, or both.

Comment: The only way I know to speed redraw when it's an issue is to utilize layers and/or hide portions of the artwork as you work. Even the beefiest, most powerful, best GPU, loaded with RAM system can be slow with Illustrator redrawing sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I have a K4000 Quadro card, Xeon e5-1650 v2, 850 Evo SSD and 16 GB of DDR3 with decent timings.  A redraw of any vector in the thousands of points gets laggy. I try to keep my pathing as simple as possible with the fewest points. Also make sure that if you are working with a decent GPU that you have updated drivers and that GPU acceleration is turned on in Illustrator preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Access the **Document Raster Effect Settings** in the drop-down **Effect** menu:

[image]

Reduce the **Resolution**:

[image]

The lower you go, the more busted up it starts to look, but the quicker it gets.
It's useful as a temporary workaround.

I asked a [similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/120215) and this solution worked well for me.